# Poner fondo de pantalla detrás de contenido

Tags: imagen

en mi archivo html, me gustaría poner una foto de fondo de pantalla detrás del contenido.

De esta forma (con el contenido delante, y la foto del buceador detrás):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo se podría hacer?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Podés compartir lo que hiciste hasta ahora? Como para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Recuerda poner que es lo que has intentado. Ya que si no lo haces normalmente la pregunta no es bien recibida.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que el atributo de background puede ser lo que necesitas.
Puedes poner en la etiqueta body dicho atributo y la imagen que deseas.

```
<body background ="imagen.jpg">
    <!-- mas html -->
</body>
```

Te dejo un link con más información:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_background.asp

Edit:

La información anterior no es soportada en HTML5.
Por lo cual es mejor usar css (no recordaba lo anterior).

```
body {
    background-image: url("imagen.gif");
   background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Si quieres que no se vea el fondo detras del texto. Puedes usar un Div y a dicho Div asignarlo un color de fondo en el css como por ejemplo el color blanco.

```
div {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Y de esta manera podrías lograr lo que buscas realizar.

Comment: No me había dado cuenta pero existe una pregunta similar. Te dejo otra explicación: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125496/background-imagen-fondo-html?rq=1